# How to change the Unity Post Processing Layer Anti Aliasing Type Through C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im wondering How to change the Unity Post Processing Layer Anti Aliasing Type Through C#, I have tried everything but can't figure it out.
I looked through the code for the layer script but still cant figure it out.

I have tried:

```
MainL.antialiasingMode = Antialiasing.[Setting];
```

[Setting] = An Antialiasing setting.

But that hasn't worked.

code:

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Rendering.PostProcessing;

public class GameQuality : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public Camera Main;
    public PostProcessVolume MainV;
    public PostProcessProfile Less;
    public PostProcessProfile High;
    public PostProcessProfile Ultra;
    public PostProcessLayer MainL;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Awake()
    {
        QualitySettings.GetQualityLevel();

        if(QualitySettings.GetQualityLevel() > 2)
        {
            MainV.profile = Less;
        }

        if(QualitySettings.GetQualityLevel() == 3)
        {
            MainV.profile = High;
        }

        if(QualitySettings.GetQualityLevel() == 4)
        {
            MainV.profile = Ultra;
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: what is your first `QualitySettings.GetQualityLevel();` for?

Comment: I don't see where exactly you tried `MainL.antialiasingMode = Antialiasing.XY` but the value of `XY` should be one of `None`, `FastApproximateAntialiasing`, `SubpixelMorphologicalAntialiasing` or `TemporalAntialiasing`. Note that you might as well have to set the according `MainL.temporalAntialiasing`, `MainL.fastApproximateAntialiasing` or `MainL.subpixelMorphologicalAntialiasing`

Comment: i had it there but deleted it as it was causing errors and i needed to other things
also when I do: MainL.antialiasingMode = Antialiasing.FastApproximateAntialiasing;
I get the error: error CS0103: The name `Antialiasing' does not exist in the current context

Comment: did you try it with `PostProcessLayer.Antialiasing`?

Comment: With using: "MainL.antialiasingMode == PostProcessLayer.Antialiasing;"



I got the error:
The name `Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement
' does not exist in the current context

Comment: if something it would have to be e.g. `MainL.antialiasingMode = PostProcessingLayer.Antialiasing.None;` since you have `using UnityEngine.Rendering.PostProcessing;` I don't see why it should not be found

Comment: it worked thank you

Comment: Please don't add an answer as edit to your question. Instead rather accept my answer if it helped you ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Post​Process​Layer.antialiasingmode](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.postprocessing@2.0/api/UnityEngine.Rendering.PostProcessing.PostProcessLayer.html) with a value of [PostProcessLayer.Antialiasing](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.postprocessing@2.0/api/UnityEngine.Rendering.PostProcessing.PostProcessLayer.Antialiasing.html) (make sure to use the full type name including the `PostProcessingLayer.`)

```
MainL.antialiasingMode = PostProcessingLayer.Antialiasing.XY;
```

where `XY` can be one out of `None`, `FastApproximateAntialiasing`, `SubpixelMorphologicalAntialiasing` or `TemporalAntialiasing`.

---

Note that this allone might not be enough. You might also have to set the values of the according antialiasing [`MainL.temporalAntialiasing`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.postprocessing@2.0/api/UnityEngine.Rendering.PostProcessing.TemporalAntialiasing.html), [`MainL.fastApproximateAntialiasing`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.postprocessing@2.0/api/UnityEngine.Rendering.PostProcessing.FastApproximateAntialiasing.html) or [`MainL.subpixelMorphologicalAntialiasing`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.postprocessing@2.0/api/UnityEngine.Rendering.PostProcessing.SubpixelMorphologicalAntialiasing.html).

---

Btw you should remove the first call of

```
QualitySettings.GetQualityLevel();
```

it just does nothing